# Prove that $F_c(G, \mathbb{C}) = \{f: G \to \mathbb{C} \mid f(ghg^{-1}) = f(h)\}$ is a vector space of $k$ dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, finite-groups

I would like that you tell me if my proof is correct ? I am learning group theory, and I forgot some basics of linear algebra so I need to do few exercices.

I want to prove that $F_c(G, \mathbb{C}) = \{f: G \to \mathbb{C} \mid f(ghg^{-1}) = f(h)\}$ is a vector space of $k$ dimension where $k$ is the number of conjugacy classes of the finite group $G$.

Let $u_i : G \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $ such as $\forall g_i \in C_i : u_i(g_i)=1$ and $\forall g \notin C_i : u_i(g)=0$ where $C_i$ is the $i$'th conjugacy class.

Clearly $u_i \in F_c(G,\mathbb{C})$.

Let $u= \sum_i \lambda_i u_i$ where $\lambda_i$ are scalars.

Then $u \in F_c(G,\mathbb{C}) $.

And we also have any element of $F_c(G,\mathbb{C})$ can be written with the above some because we have total freedom on the scalars $\lambda_i$ (so we can reach any value of the function for any conjugacy class).

As we have $k$ conjugacy classes, we have $k$ elements in the sum.

The final step is to prove that the $(u_i)_i$ family is free. We just have to write :

$ \sum_i \beta_k u_k = 0$, and by successive evaluations on the conjugacy classes we find that $\forall k :\beta_k = 0$. Thus we have a free and generating family of our vector space.

Thus the vector space is of dimension $k$.

Am I right or did i forgot smthing / made mistake in my proof ?

Comment: This is correct.